# Understanding Asynchronous / Overlapped IO

Tags: c++, winapi

I am learning about Asynchronous / Overlapped IO in windows. I have written the following code, but it doesn't compile. Where is my mistake? I don't know why we need to call something as FileIoCompletionRoutine and how should I define it?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

VOID WINAPI FileIOCompletionRoutine(DWORD, DWORD, LPOVERLAPPED);
HANDLE g_HandleEvent;

wchar_t string_data[] = L"Garbage data is absloute thing";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    g_HandleEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    auto file_name = L"Cayot.txt";
    auto handle_file = CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

    if (handle_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "File creation is failed." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    OVERLAPPED overlapped_instance = { 0 };
    overlapped_instance.hEvent = g_HandleEvent;

    WriteFileEx(handle_file, string_data, sizeof(string_data), &overlapped_instance, FileIOCompletionRoutine);

    SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);

    return 0;
}
```

Error compiler:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall
> FileIOCompletionRoutine(unsigned long,unsigned long,struct _OVERLAPPED
> *)" (?FileIOCompletionRoutine@@YGXKKPAU_OVERLAPPED@@@Z)

Comment: What does the compiler tell you the problem is?

Comment: @interjay error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall FileIOCompletionRoutine(unsigned long,unsigned long,struct _OVERLAPPED *)" (?FileIOCompletionRoutine@@YGXKKPAU_OVERLAPPED@@@Z)

Comment: Where do you define (implement) the `FileIOCompletionRoutine` function? The linker says that it's missing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't know how should i define it?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/nc-minwinbase-lpoverlapped_completion_routine)?

Comment: you need **implement** *FileIOCompletionRoutine*, not simply define

Comment: @RbMm That's kind of what "define" means, the definition is the implementation of something. Perhaps you think about the *declaration* (which the OP have)?

Comment: @Cayoot What the definition of the function would be is up to you, the main thing is that you do define the function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - yes, my mistake. i mean that exist only *declaration* of function. but need *implementation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have merely forward-declared the `FileIOCompletionRoutine()` function, which satisfies the compiler, but you have not actually implemented the function, so the linker fails to find it.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

VOID WINAPI FileIOCompletionRoutine(DWORD, DWORD, LPOVERLAPPED);

HANDLE g_HandleEvent;
wchar_t string_data[] = L"Garbage data is absloute thing";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    g_HandleEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    auto file_name = L"Cayot.txt";
    auto handle_file = CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

    if (handle_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "File creation is failed." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    OVERLAPPED overlapped_instance = { 0 };
    overlapped_instance.hEvent = g_HandleEvent;

    WriteFileEx(handle_file, string_data, sizeof(string_data), &overlapped_instance, FileIOCompletionRoutine);

    SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);

    return 0;
}

VOID WINAPI FileIOCompletionRoutine(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    // Do something here...
}
```